# Jointly Gaussian and Brownian bridge

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, solution-verification

> let $X_t = B(t) - tB(1)$, for $t \in[0,1]$ the classical Brownian Bridge.
>
> Let also $s \leq t$: why are $X_t$ and $X_t - \frac{1-t}{1-s} X_s$ jointly Gaussian?

I just  know that $(X_t)$ is a Gaussian process and I'm able to show it: basically one takes a partition of $[0,1]$ and see that $(X_{t_1}, \ldots, X_{t_n})$ is the image via a linear mapping of $(B(t_1), \ldots, B(t_n), B(1))$.

**Edit**
I think I found the answer by myself, but a check would br really appreciated.

So clearly the vector $(X_t - \frac{1-t}{1-s}X_s, X_s)$ is a linear map of the vector $(X_t,X_s)$. So the questions is: is the vector $(X_t,X_s)$ Gaussian?

Now, I look at each component:$(B(t) - tB(1), B(s)-sB(1))$. Again, this is a linear map of the vector $(B(s),B(t),B(1))$ **which is a Gaussian vector because $(B_t)$ is a Brownian motion**

This concludes the proof

Comment: The definition of a Gaussian vector that I know relates to the joint distribution being given in the form of a joint Gaussian, which in this context amounts to saying that $(X_t,X_s)=a+Cn$ where $a$ is some vector depending on $t,s$, $C$ is the covariance matrix, and $n$ is a vector of two iid N(0,1)s. A process being Gaussian tells you that all finite dimensional distributions are Gaussian in this sense.

Comment: I'm changing my question, maybe now it's cleares

Comment: @Ian thanks for the comment. I edited my question. Basically I understand the definition. My difficulty is in how to show it explicitely.

Comment: @Ian I tried to answer to my question in the edit: could you please check it?

Comment: Sure, you can do it that way if you like.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! ;) So jointly gaussian means actually that the I can write  the vector $(X_t,X_s)$ as a linear map of a gaussian vector, right? @Ian

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply a Gaussian random vector by a constant matrix (i.e. a non-random matrix) then what you get is always a Gaussian random vector.

You have independent Gaussians $B_t$ and $B_1-B_t.$ Independent univariate Gaussians are jointly Gaussian. Your random vector is tuple of a constant linear combinations of these two.

Comment: Thanks. So you also confirm that my approach is okay (the one in the edit) ?  I wanted to see it explcitely @MichaelHardy

Comment: @Vefhug Yes, what you wrote is correct.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Hi Michael, could you help me solve this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3719515/brownian-bridge-for-w-w-t-t-in-t-0-1 Many thanks!